# Executing a command from OptionMenu

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, popup, frames, toplevel

Is there a way to make an options menu perform a command from a range of different commands?

```
from tkinter import *
#creates 2 windows
root = Tk()
popup = Toplevel()

#places frame in popup window
popup_frame = Frame(popup)
popup_frame.pack()

#4 functions, text is just placeholder for idea
def popup1(popup):
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup1 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique textfor popup1")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup1.pack()

def popup2(popup):
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup2 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique text for popup2")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup2.pack()

def popup3(popup):
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup3 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique text for popup3")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup3.pack()

def popup1(popup):
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup4 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique text for popup4")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup4.pack()

#2 option menus offering different selections
options1 = ["popup1", "popup2"]
variable1 = StringVar()
drop_title1 = StringVar(root)
#sets initial name for widget
drop_title1.set("Please Choose Options 1 Or 2")
dropdownmenu1 = OptionMenu(root, drop_title1, *options, command=lambda:func())
dropdownmenu1.place(x=10, y=10)

options2 = ["popup3", "popup4"]
variable2 = StringVar()
drop_title2 = StringVar(root)
drop_title2 .set("Please Choose Options 3 Or 4")
dropdownmenu2 = OptionMenu(root, drop_title2, *options, command=lambda:func())
dropdownmenu2.place(x=100, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

So there is the root frame with 2 different dropdown menus in it, where if you clicked on say option 1, the popup_frame would be deleted and replaced with the contents of option 1, then from the second drop-down menu, option 4 is selected and the contents of the popup_frame change to what option 4 contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function defined as `command` for the `OptionMenu` will be given the selected value as argument. So you can define the callback function to check that value and call another function depending on which value it is:

```
from tkinter import *
#creates 2 windows
root = Tk()
popup = Toplevel()

#places frame in popup window
popup_frame = Frame(popup)
popup_frame.pack()

#4 functions, text is just placeholder for idea
def popup1():
    global popup_frame
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup1 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique text for popup1")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup1.pack()

def popup2():
    global popup_frame
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup2 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique text for popup2")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup2.pack()

def popup3():
    global popup_frame
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup3 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique text for popup3")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup3.pack()

def popup4():
    global popup_frame
    popup_frame.destroy()
    popup_frame = Frame(popup)
    label_popup4 = Label(popup_frame, text="unique text for popup4")
    popup_frame.pack()
    label_popup4.pack()

def func(val):
    if val == "popup1":
        popup1()
    elif val == "popup2":
        popup2()
    elif val == "popup3":
        popup3()
    elif val == "popup4":
        popup4()

#2 option menus offering different selections
options1 = ["popup1", "popup2"]
variable1 = StringVar()
drop_title1 = StringVar(root)
#sets initial name for widget
drop_title1.set("Please Choose Options 1 Or 2")
dropdownmenu1 = OptionMenu(root, drop_title1, *options1, command=func)
dropdownmenu1.pack(side=LEFT)

options2 = ["popup3", "popup4"]
variable2 = StringVar()
drop_title2 = StringVar(root)
drop_title2 .set("Please Choose Options 3 Or 4")
dropdownmenu2 = OptionMenu(root, drop_title2, *options2, command=func)
dropdownmenu2.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Always been told to avoid global variable as they cause issues, but either way thanks, It does what I need it too.

Comment: Well yeah, but when you want to manipulate a variable that's created in the global namespace from a function you have to. You could put your GUI in a Class, which lets you save the widgets as class variables and avoid global variables. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/3714930) for a nice template to do this.